# ARR on IIS to skip windows authentication

Tags: iis, arr

I have a network with DMZ, where my application is deployed.

My application is deployed in IIS on a server in the internal network. On this IIS, 'Windows Authentication' is enabled for my application.

I have another IIS in the DMZ where I have used ARR (Application Request Rewrite) to route all requests to the internal server where my application is hosted. On this IIS, 'Anonymous Authentication is enabled'

When I try to access my application from public internet (through DMZ), the browser displays the authentication popup. But for users from public internet does not have windows account in the domain.

Is there any configuration that can authenticate internal users on their windows account and external users without it?

Comment: I've usually found the easiest way to do this to be to run two separate instances of the site. One configured with Windows Auth, the other without it. It's very difficult to mix Windows Auth with anything else in a single site. Another alternative to to use Forms authentication (which easily allows anonymous users), and if they need to access an area of the site that requires auth, have the user enter their Windows credentials into a form, which you can then verify via a call to Active Directory.

Comment: Thank you! My guess is in line with your suggestion.... Will wait for a while for any new surprises...